# How to manually change the index file (.ind) to achieve correct order for foreign letters?

Tags: symbols, indexing, alphabet

I am using MikTex,pdfLaTex, WinXP_SP3. I want to create an index including foreign letters in correct alphabetical order. Using Xindy seems like a lot of hassle, so I would like to avoid it.  How can I manually change the index file (`.ind`) after it is created, setting the entries in the correct alphabetical order?

I am going to answer my own question.

The preamble contains

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3,  intoc]
```

I have tried using `makeidx`, but it didn't work so I changed to `imakeidx`.

At the end of the file there is

```
\clearpage
\printindex
```

With this setup, an index file is created and printed, but with all words starting with foreign characters at the front, which is incorrect.

Open the `.ind` file with notepad. Manually copy-paste the incorrectly placed entries into proper places, adding `\indexspace` entries as required. (This is easier done in wordpad, actually). Now make the following changes to the preamble:

```
%\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\makeindex[columns=3,  intoc]
```

The otherwise failed makeidx now prints the manually altered index file. Even the TOC entry of the index remains. Job done.

Answer (score 2):

### XIndy

You may consider switching to XIndy, a much more powerful index generator, which supports sorting rules for many languages.

### Helping Makeindex

The sorting of Makeindex can be influenced by specifying a sorting key. In the default setting, the character `@` separates the sorting key from the word, which appears in the index, e.g.: `\index{Strasse@Straße}`,
`\index{Baecker@Bäcker}`/`\index{Backer@Bäcker}` (depending on the sorting rule). Then Makeindex will sort the entries as `Strasse` and `Baecker`/`Backer`, but `Straße` and `Bäcker` will appear in the index.

### Sorting of the `.idx` file

The previous method can also be used to write a script, which provides sort keys for the entries in the `.idx` file. However, new letter groups are not possible.

### Sorting of the `.ind` file

Parsing the `.ind` file is more cumbersome. A style file could be written to add more logical markup to ease the parsing. After identifying the entries, the script could perform its own sorting, including adding new letter groups.